# Use of new vs default for Structure Construction in Rust

Tags: rust, struct, constructor

I see some structures in Rust use a `default` for there construction, while I see others use `new`.<sup>1</sup> Is there any semantic difference between the use of `new` vs `default`, or is everything convention? And if it is convention, is there any official standards on what that convention/style is?

I do see that there is a [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait, with a macro that creates a default `default` function for simple structs, where as I do not see a similar thing for `new`. This makes me guess that `new` is meant for the actual constructor, while `default` is mostly just meant when using the struct in other data structures. But I cannot find anything that states that is correct or incorrect.<sup>2</sup>

Finally, does it matter if the constructor has (possibly optional) parameters for building the structure? It looks like `default` works best if it takes no arguments, but I'm not confident of this. For simple constructors say a point class:

```
#[defive(Default)]
pub struct Point {
    pub x: u32, 
    pub y: u32,
    pub z: u32
}
```

Users could construct it by using:

```
Point {x: 42, ..Default::default()}
```

But that only works if all of the fields a user might change are public.

In conclusion, when is it appropriate to use `new` vs `default` when constructing structures in Rust, both when a constructor takes no arguments, or possibly optional arguments?

<sub><sup>1</sup> I also see a few others just use the name of the structure, but I think that's deprecated?</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> It might be possible that it is neither correct nor incorrect, making it subjective and not really appropriate on stack overflow. Because of this ambiguity I think that even if it is subjective, it *is* objective to state that its subjective, making it again appropriate for SO.</sub>

Comment: I think you'll see `new` used more often than it necessarily should be because languages like C++, Java, and even JavaScript and Ruby have beaten it into us as being necessary. `Default` really is the way to go for default "constructors", but it may still seem odd to anyone who's not totally doing things the Rust way. You note `Default` can't take any arguments, while `new` can, but you don't need to use the function name `new`, either, and you'll see a lot of Rust libraries go in other directions for their constructor(s).

Comment: A nuanced discussion of this topic was held at [Should `Foo::new() -> Foo` just be `impl Default for Foo`?](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/should-foo-new-foo-just-be-impl-default-for-foo/69417?u=y.e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not think of the question as `new()` vs. `default()`, but rather `new()` vs. `Default`. It's not that `Default` provides a convenient `default()`, it's that `default()` is the function name for `Default` — it would be unidiomatic to write a `fn default()` that is *not* an implementation of `Default`.

If your type has a reasonable way to construct it without any data, an “empty” value of its type, then it should:

- Implement `Default`. This way, other types containing yours can benefit from it in their own `Default`, and in general you get all the benefits of [implementing common traits](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#types-eagerly-implement-common-traits-c-common-traits).
- Provide a `new()` with no parameters, *if* there isn't already a more natural `new()` that takes parameters.

  (For example, [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html), [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html), and other containers of a single value will typically have a `new()` with one parameter, but also implement `Default` by calling the inner type's `Default::default()`. In that case, `new()` and `default()` are *not* the same.)
- If possible, make the `new()` function (whether or not it has parameters) a `const fn`. This allows callers to create values of your type at compile time, which is useful for things like initializing `static` variables and `const`s with initially-empty or always-empty values.

  (Trait implementations cannot yet have `const fn`s, so this is a benefit of providing a function even when you *also* implement `Default`.)

Comment: I will add that `Default` is used in generic code (including std) so you should implement it, and that in the case mentioned in the question there is the builder pattern.